# Isolation Forest for Anomaly Detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, anomaly-detection, industrial

In this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_isolation_forest.html) of `IsolationForest` for Anomaly Detection:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

# Generate train data
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(100, 2)
X_train = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some regular novel observations
X = 0.3 * rng.randn(20, 2)
X_test = np.r_[X + 2, X - 2]
# Generate some abnormal novel observations
X_outliers = rng.uniform(low=-4, high=4, size=(20, 2))

# fit the model
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng)
clf.fit(X_train)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_test = clf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_outliers = clf.predict(X_outliers)
```

I believe that the outliers in this code were randomly introduced.
But, if I am doing an Anomaly Detection with real-life data, then:

- How do I take this forward?
- How to identify Anomalies if I have a dataset already?
  I'm trying my hands on Combined Cycle Power Plant [dataset](https://github.com/S-B-Iqbal/Predicting-Power-Output-of-a-combined-cycle-power-plant.).
  OR, if you have any other good anomaly detection practice datasets drop some links!

Comment: What do you mean "how do I take this forward" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for the contamination in the dataset. Then you need to check the contamination parameter.

clf = IsolationForest(max_samples=100, random_state=rng, contamination='auto')

[image]

It is based on the assumption that data has certain level of contamination.

Answer (score 0):

The `rng` is random number. You can consider it as synthetic dataset. For real-world dataset, you have to load it by using `load` function of `numpy` or `pandas`.

You can find some datasets for anomaly detection task here http://odds.cs.stonybrook.edu

So far, I can say that Prophet is a popular framework for time series analysis tasks which include anomaly detection for streaming data https://www.kaggle.com/vinayjaju/anomaly-detection-using-facebook-s-prophet